# Ping website from MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ping

I'm hosted a MySql database on Amazon RDS, and I'm looking to create a Stored Procedure that will ping my NAS at home and log the results to a table. I'm looking to create a log of my home internet outages.

I'm new to MySql and have no idea how to ping something from a Stored Procedure, and every search on google appears to be on how to ping a MySql server, not how to ping *from* a MySql stored procedure.

In mssql I can ping using the following method:

```
DECLARE @pingAddress VARCHAR(200) = 'ping www.google.ca'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @pingAddress
```

Is there anyway to achieve the same affect in MySql?

Comment: Sounds like you might be doing something analogous to using a hammer to drive screws.  Why do you want to use MySql for this task?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea exec ping from one Stored Procedure. Why not create one scheduler to do this.

Comment: This sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676); it seems like an unusual thing to want to do. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? What should the end result be? How does **this approach** help you get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't ping or do anything else outside the database in a stored procedure. Stored procedures are for manipulating data in MySQL.

If you want to log your home internet outages, there are services that do that for you, for example https://www.pingdom.com/free

If you prefer to do it yourself with custom code, write an application and host it on a small EC2 instance, or else run a Lambda function on a schedule or something like that.

Here's a blog about how one person did it with a Lambda: https://medium.com/@nzoschke/http-service-health-monitor-w-lambda-a9f475abbbf4

Comment: I know c# and sql, and was hoping that MySql might also have something that I could quickly throw together for some testing. But I like the Lambda approach, I'll have to do a crash course on Python to understand his script, but I think I'll try that approach.

Comment: Yeah, but MySQL is not an application server, you shouldn't treat it like Oracle PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In a native MySQL unextended by user-defined functions, You Can't Do That™.

There may be a suitable set of user-defined functions if you must do it. But doing this sort of thing within a MySQL database is something zealously to be avoided.

Here is the UDF repository. 
https://github.com/mysqludf